# Java constructor branching

Tags: java, class, constructor

I have a constructor which accepts an argument, which may be invalid; if it is invalid, I want it to run the constructor's no-argument constructor instead. Otherwise, it should proceed with the given input and do multiple things with that input.

Unfortunately, Java for some reason forces constructor calls to be in the first statement. Is there any way to get around this beyond duplicating code? (my inner programmer dislikes this!)

Ideally, my code in question would work something like this:

```
public Constructor() {
    super();
    // some constructor code
}

public Constructor(Object arg) {
    if (arg == null) {
        this(); // calls the first constructor instead of proceeding
        return;
    }

    super();
    /** 
     * some code to handle the new input,
     * if it isn't null
    **/
}
```

However, this obviously isn't possible in Java due to any constructor statements needing to be in the very first statement. Is there an elegant/correct way to deal with this? I was unable to find anything online beyond constructor chaining, which is something else.

Comment: Souds like you are looking for the builder pattern

Comment: Work is underway to allow statements before an explicit constructor invocation. See [*JEP 447: Statements before super(...)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/447), previewing in Java 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the code you want to run in the parameterless constructor into the one-parameter constructor:

```
public YourClass(Object arg) {
    super();
    if (arg == null) {

        // move the code in the parameterless constructor here...

        return;
    }

    /** 
     * some code to handle the new input,
     * if it isn't null
    **/
}
```

Now, the parameterless constructor doesn't need to duplicate that code again - it can just call the one-parameter constructor with `null`:

```
public YourClass() {
    this(null);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if passing an "invalid" argument to the one-parameter constructor is not an easy thing to do (e.g. if `null` is a valid value, and invalid values are identified by inspecting the object itself), you can write everything in a private constructor with a `boolean` argument, and do the branching using that.

The idea is basically to have *one* constructor that every other constructor delegates to, similar to how classes in Kotlin must have a primary constructor.

```
// you should be able to name the parameters with better names :)
private YourClass(Object arg, boolean parameterlessImplementation) {
    if (parameterlessImplementation || !isValid(arg)) {
        // move the code in the parameterless constructor here...
    } else {
        // do things with arg
    }
}

public YourClass(Object arg) {
    this(arg, false);
}

public YourClass() {
    this(null, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, the cleanest solution (IMO too much logic in the constructor makes it hard to read) is to use static factory method:

```
public class MyClass {

  private MyClass() {
    super();
  }

  public static MyClass create(Object arg) {
    if (arg == null) {
      return new MyClass();
    }
    //handle the input
    //possibly create the instance with another constructor, etc.
  }
}
```

Notice how I made the contructor private, in this case I want all object creation to go through the factory method.

Comment: A slight caveat of this is that some final fields may need to be initialised in the one-parameter constructor, and cannot be initialised in a factory method. Of course, this can be solved by just writing an extra one-parameter private constructor. That constructor would not validate the parametes, and instead, `create` would delegate to, when `arg` is not null.

Comment: @Sweeper This is true, but it can be easily solved by having a primary constructor and other constructors, which delegate to it. Then OP just needs to pick the correct one depending on `arg`. Of course, if the object is complicated and this would mean too many constructors, a builder may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use what we call a **Factory**.
A factory is a class that creates objects of a specific class or family of classes.

Usually, the factory class has only one method called getX or createX (X the name of your class) and takes constructor parameters.
Inside that method you can determine which constuctor to use.

Heres an example for creating a **Car** object:

The Car class goes like this

```
public class Car {
private String name;
private int speed;

public Car(String name, int speed) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
}

public Car() {
    this("No name", 0);
}
```

}

Then we need the factory

```
public class CarFactory {

public Car createCar(String name, int speed) {
    if(name == null || speed < 0) {
        return new Car();
    }

    else {
        return new Car(name, speed);
    }
}
```

}

Finally we use the factory to create the Cars in a main method.

```
public class Example {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarFactory factory = new CarFactory();

    Car car1 = factory.createCar("Ferrari", 200);
    Car car2 = factory.createCar(null, 200);
    
    System.out.println(car1);
    System.out.println(car2);
}
```

}

Hope this hepls!